# React app component is not reading the current_user data despite it being accessed only after authentication has successfully taken place

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

My app consists of a React-Redux front-end with a Rails back-end. The "AddCreation" component is on a protected route that can only be accessed after the user has logged-in successfully. Here is what the routing looks like on the App.js:

```
function App() {
  const { authChecked, loggedIn } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login loggedIn={loggedIn} />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes isAllowed={loggedIn} authChecked={authChecked} redirectPath="/login" />}>
          <Route path="/creations" element={<Creations />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<AddCreation />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

The "AddCreation" component requires not only that the user logs in successfully, but that he be an admin, otherwise, he is redirected to the "Creations" component. This is the pertinent piece of code in the "AddCreation" component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser.role !== 'admin') {
      navigate("/creations");
    }
  }, [currentUser.role, navigate]);
```

For some reason, the app keeps redirecting me to "Creations" Component in spite of me loging-in as "admin". The "admin" is a user that has been seeded into the back-end Rails app and is accessed by supplying the appropriate username and password (the role of admin is denoted by 1).

The admin user as set in db/seeds:

```
user_1 = User.create(username: 'Admin User', role: 1, email: 'admin@gmail.com', password: "admin123")
```

This user passes through the following method in User model, so that users with role=1 become admins and all other users are treated as regular users:

```
enum role: %i[user admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, if: :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end
```

And the User serializer sends the role to the Registrations and sessions controllers:

```
class UserSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :id, :username, :role, :email
end
```

Here is the pertinent line from the Registrations and the Sessions controllers:

```
data: UserSerializer.new(resource).serializable_hash[:data] [:attributes]
```

I have been going around in circles trying to figure out what is wrong with the "AddCreation" component, that makes it fail to read the current_user data.

Here is the "AddCreation" component with a portion of the value input fields omitted for brevity:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getToken } from '../redux/actions/auth';
import axios from 'axios';

const AddCreation = () => {
  const { reset } = useForm();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [creation, setCreation] = useState({});
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser.role !== 'admin') {
      navigate("/creations");
    }
  }, [currentUser.role, navigate]);
 
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    setCreation({ ...creation, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    const img = document.getElementById('art_image');

    data.append('image_url', img.files[0]);
    // data.append('journeyman_id', parseInt(id, 10));
    data.append('artist', creation.artist);
    data.append('title', creation.title);
    data.append('type_of_work', creation.type_of_work);
    data.append('medium', creation.medium);
    data.append('dimensions', creation.dimensions);
    data.append('date_of_composition', creation.date_of_composition);
    data.append('art_category', creation.art_category);
    data.append('comment', creation.comment);
    data.append('price', creation.price);

    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/v1/creations', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Authorization: getToken(),
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        navigate('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    reset();
  };

  return (
    <main className="">
      <div className="my-5 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <h2>Add a Creation to Listing</h2>
        <form className="my-5 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center border border-dark" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="my-5 mx-5">
            
            <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between my-3">
              <label
                className=""
                htmlFor="artist-name"
              >
                Artist Name:
              </label>
              <input
                className=""
                id="artist"
                type="text"
                name="artist"
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
            </div>
           
... the rest of the input fields were omitted for brevity...

          
            <div className="my-3">
              <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" >
                Add Creation
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default AddCreation;
```

I'd really appreciate any suggestions that can help me disentangle this mess. I am suspecting that this particular component (the "AddCreation") is not connecting to the back end, but I have no idea why, being that the Login and Signup components connect just fine. If further info is needed, here are the repo addresses for the front and the back-ends:

https://github.com/German-Cobian/Art-Market-Front-End
https://github.com/German-Cobian/Art-Market-Rails

So far, I have tried to "console.log" the currentUser username, role and password, but I get "undefined" as a response.

Comment: If you opened up the console and typed in `1 !== "admin"` what do you suspect the result would be? You could either change the condition to `currentUser.role !== 1` or change the user object to have `role: "admin"`.

Comment: I apologize, Drew. I did not realize in my question how incomplete the explanation of my app's functioning was. I have added all the information that is pertinent now. I did try your solution of changing the condition to `currentUser.role !== 1` and it was to no avail. It really seems as if, for some reason, this component is not connecting to the backend, even though the Login and Signup components are doing so successfully.

Comment: How far does the `AddCreation` component get in submitting the form data? Is the request made to the network? If so what is the result? Are there any errors?

Comment: So is a request being made to the backend API successfully? If so, then how is the request handled in the backend? Any errors?

Comment: From the backend I get the following: `Completed 400 Bad Request in 110ms … ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: creation Did you mean?  action): app/controllers/v1/creations_controller.rb:52:in 'creation_params'
app/controllers/v1/creations_controller.rb:22:in 'create'` I have checked the creation_params, and the are all well-stated and complete.

Comment: Looks like something is missing in the backend controllers? I don't know anything about Rails so I'm afraid I won't be much help from here.

Comment: I am very grateful for the help you were able to offer me.